# The operation can only be performed from a drillthrough report

Tags: rdlc

```
  protected void ReportViewer1_Back(object sender, BackEventArgs e)
    {       
        GetReportData();
    }
```

**The operation can only be performed from a drillthrough report**  this error is throw when i use report viewer back button event for reload parent report ..

This is `GetReportData()` method

```
protected void GetReportData()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet dsreport = bd.bStatePerfomanceReport(Convert.ToInt32(ddlYear.SelectedValue), reportdetail.month, Convert.ToInt32(rdbCol.SelectedValue));
            ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
            ReportViewer1.Reset();
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            LocalReport rep = ReportViewer1.LocalReport;
            rep.Refresh();
            rep.ReportPath = "rdlc/StateataGlance.rdlc";
            rds.Name = "dsReport_uspReport_StateataGlance";
            rds.Value = dsreport.Tables[0];
            rep.DataSources.Add(rds);

            ReportParameter[] parms = new ReportParameter[3];
            parms[0] = new ReportParameter("month", ddlMonth.SelectedItem.Text + ",  " + ddlYear.SelectedItem.Text, true);
            parms[1] = new ReportParameter("mo", ddlMonth.SelectedValue, true);
            parms[2] = new ReportParameter("year", ddlYear.SelectedValue, true);
            this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parms);
            rep.Refresh();
            ViewState["level"] = 0;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

and its working on page load event but when i call same method on back button event its throw an error .

Comment: Are you using SubReport?

Comment: not i am using drilled through report